# Adding a custom list column to site column in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list

I created an Import Spreadsheet list in order to import a list of excel data into my list, now the list have some new custom columns independent to the actual default site columns. 
Now I want to create a view filtering on that particular custom column, which obviously isn't available in the filter column list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Importing from Excel always re-create columns starting with headers (if any or use Column 1,2,3) and ignore any site columns you might have defined. Columns will be bound to the List which also means that you seem like filtering your site column which actually is not.

There is no way to directly import from Excel into an existing list but you could have a console application doing it for you or simply use the datasheet view and copy&paste.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

Filtering is supported for both, site or list level columns.It is not necessary to have custom columns as site columns for that.

Comment: if that is the case I can't see that particular column which came from the excel in my list filter.

Comment: not sure why but it appears... in my case I see